# Do Ahsoka's face markings have any meaning?

Tags: ahsoka-tano, ahsoka-series

I'm assuming that her face markings are not a natural component of her physiology.

So do the markings on Ahsoka's face have any special meaning?  And when in her life did she receive them?

Comment: I would not assume that. We see some pretty young Togruta with facial pigmentation, and we know that Togruta frequently have alternating colors on their lekku and montrals as a form of evolved camouflage, apparently.

Answer (score 6):

We actually do see Ahsoka as a newborn in *Tales of the Jedi* (Season 1, Episode 1).

[image]

She has *some* facial markings at birth, though later in the episode the elder does 'bless' her "for luck". So she is born with *some* form of pigmentation, and her lekku looks different compared to the adults and what she looked like later.

Basically she was born with it, and the markings change with age.

[image]

This photo is a 'year' later according to the dialog in that episode

However, the markings we see on most Togruta are the same colour as her natural ones.

Most of the markings we see are the pale white though.

As a comparison, this is her as a young adult during the Imperial period - episode 6 of the same series, which is set right after/during Order 66.

Details tend to change during different media - *Clone Wars*/*Tales of the Jedi*/live action - but clearly she was born with it and it changes, rather than it having special meaning.

[image]

(Another point of comparison might be season 1 episode 5 of *Ahsoka*, which has her as a Padawan, and there's a *Clone Wars* episode of the same period in her life. But that's probably for a later edit)

Comment: +1 Interesting! I haven't seen Tales of the Jedi and I always assumed they were face tattoos.

Comment: It would be good if you could show a progression from simple dots to extensive patterns.  BTW from what I remember of that Ahsoka episode, she appeared to have the same markings when portrayed as both an adult and Padawan.

Comment: Well, they don't really show it - I would be happy to update it with more data points if I come across them but we don't have much of her pre Padawan, and I am still working through the clone wars and rebels.